# What module do I use for AirflowHelpers.base_utils what has get_airflow_version, get_airflow_home_directory changed to?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have some python airflow dag code that I have inherited and I am not sure where certain module operators are now.
The line I am getting an error on is:

from AirflowHelpers.base_utils import get_airflow_version, get_airflow_home_directory, AIRFLOW_TYPE

That AirflowHelpers is an unresolved reference and I cannot find a module for this to install. I'd thought it was in the airflow.utils.helpers but I do not see anything related to get_airflow_version, get_airflow_home_directory or AIRFLOW_TYPE

Were these moved to a different module within airflow and if so which submodule are these buried in? Even a pointer to searchable documentation would help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was an internally created module.